# Extracting only black text from a pdf

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, text-extraction

I have a bunch of pdf files containing song lyrics (in black font) and chords (in blue font) right in between the letters.

Is it possible to extract only the text in black font and omit all the text in other colors?

Answer (score 0):

You could, with considerable effort, do this in Ghostscript, but it would mean altering the PDF interpreter specially for the task (no mean feat).

You'd need to know the exact colour you wanted to drop (or alternatively, keep). Then you modify each of the text showing operators (TJ, Tj, ' and ") which are defined in /ghostpdl/Resource/Init/pdf_ops.ps. You start by checking the current colour, if its one you want you go ahead and process the text, otherwise pop the string and return without processing.

Note that you'll either need to rebuild Ghostscript, or tell it to use the modified files by using the -I switch on the command line.

Run the original PDF file as teh input, select the pdfwrite device and create a new file where the text will be missing.

This may give unexpected results where the following text relies on the current point being moved by the preceding operation. In this case you could try altering the colour to white before drawing it. This itself has drawbacks; if the page isn't white underneath the text will still show up, copy and paster will still pick up the white text, even if its invisible.